# How to check if form.reset() has changed anything

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

Is there a way in js to check if the `reset()` functionality of a form has really changed something or not.
Reset resets the form inputs to the default. But if the current values are already the default values, I want to notice that the `reset()` had no effect. In case `reset()` changed something I want to call `foo()`, in case reset had no effect I want to call `bar()`.
Is this elegantly possible without comparing every input field before and after?

Comment: A snapshot of before and after calling `form.reset()`?

Comment: But i would have to compare the snapshots input fields one by one, that was my first idea but that doesn't feel elegant

Comment: Not extremely elegant, but you could check if each field is pristine/dirty when you call reset

Comment: I think that you asking this question is a bad symptom. Your client should keep the state of the form somewhere, and along with the state you should also maintain the initial state. Once you have both, you can easily check if the reset changed something (actually you couldn't use reset at all!)

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `form.reset()`, try to compare the current values to the default (in `value` attribute) values:

```
const hasChanged = Array.from(form.elements).some(x => {
    const attrValue = x.getAttribute('value') || '';
    return x.value !== attrValue;
});

form.reset();

if (hasChanged)
    foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Short (but not the best) way using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData):

```js
const form = document.forms[0];

function run() {
  const data = new FormData(form);
  form.reset();
  const resetData = new FormData(form);
  if (
   JSON.stringify([...data.entries()]) ===
   JSON.stringify([...resetData.entries()])
  ){
    console.log('foo');
  } else {
    console.log('bar');
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
<input name=i1 />
<input name=i2 />
</form>
<button onclick="run()">Reset & Check</button>
```

Comment: fyi, it's possible to remove `.entries()`